# How to hide a column in a jqgrid subgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How do I hide a column in a subgrid?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? thanks

Comment: i have a grid, with a subgrid, and i have to hide the first col (id) in the grid and the subgrid.

Answer (score 1):

In model of subgrid just add `hidden:true`

More model options can be found here:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options